# Mapping upper left esc key to fn

Tags: kde, xkb, xmodmap

Is it possible to map the upper left `esc` key to `fn`? How?
Apparently `xmodmap` is deprecated and you should use something like `setxkbmap` instead.

I tried something like:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 1 = 464"
```

where `esc` has keycode 1 and `fn` has keycode 464, but I got the error:

```
xmodmap:  commandline:1:  bad keycode value (out of range)
xmodmap:  1 error encountered, aborting.
```

System information:

```
Linux 5.19.0-46-generic #47~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Jun 21 15:35:31 UTC 2 x86_64
```

(Kde Neon on a Macbook Pro 2015).

Comment: I don't know about MacBookPros specifically, but `fn` keys are often hardwired by the hardware and not visible to the OS. As is `fn`+F1 sends a different keycode from F1 and no information to the OS that a `fn` key was pressed. Where did you get that `464` from?

Comment: I used `sudo showkey` to get the respective keycodes.  In the man page of `showkey`, it says something cryptic about keycodes larger than 127 being in three bytes, but I honestly don't quite get it. I'll look more into `setxkbmap` today and hopefully I can get a solution.